# Nova 2.0 Ordering of Resource Groups

Tags: laravel-nova, laravel-6

Using Laravel 6.x and Nova 2.0, does anyone have any tips or advice on re-ordering of resource groups when using the $group variable on resources?

By default it orders groups on the navbar alphabetically but I'd like to re-order the groups manually.

Thanks!